# Universal "HTTP GET html page content and recode to UTF-8" procedure

Tags: ruby, encoding, get, html

For some time I have been trying to solve fairly common problem consisting of basically three steps:

1. fetch html page with specified URL and store its content in a String
2. detect content encoding either from html meta information or HTTP header
3. recode the content into UTF-8 for further processing

In the real usage I have the first step a little extended with functionalities like having a "user-agent" instance with cookie-jar, configurable timeout and amount of GET attempts, configurable request count per time frame limitation, etc...

I implemented `rest-client` wrapper but I run into several problems:

- class-global `RestClient.proxy` settings conflicting with e.g. `couchrest` (using `rest-client` itself)
- freezing: sometimes the timeout causes freezing of the process. AFAIK more of my friends run into the same problem with `rest-client`
- redirect `Location` URI parsing: `rest-client` fails to fetch "http://www.ofertacarioca.com.br/index.aspx?cidade=4,Belo%20Horizonte" correctly complaining about invalid URI '/indexnew.aspx?cidade=4,Belo Horizonte' in `Location` header of the 302 result but `curb` handles this perfectly through to the target page. I'm about to reimplement the wrapper with the use of `curb`
- recoding problems in the third step: I attempted to detect encoding from html page meta information and HTTP header (in this order) for some pages still to no avail

I would love to know of some cool gem out there that would handle such needs or of some intriguing universal solution hints if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has answered, I needed to implement the `curb`-based solution:
[curburger](https://github.com/geronime/curburger)

Perhaps somebody finds it useful.